Using st.session_state in a streamlit web application that has been packaged into an .exe file
I used PyInstaller to package my streamlit python web application into an .exe file. However, I ran into some issues while trying to open my exe file (main.exe). If I click on the .exe file, I get the following error: Session state does not function when running a script without streamlit run
And when I try to run streamlit run main.exe on my terminal, it still doesn't work, because streamlit run can only operate with .py files and not .exe files. How do I then open my .exe file and also use st.session_state? Or is there any alternative to st.session_state?
I tried using global variables but they do not update my elements because the elements (text input, file uploader) themselves are not re-rendered; doing st.rerun() does not re-render and update the values for my elements as well.
Note: I am using st.session_state to change the values and keys of my st.text_input at st.file_uploader
Thanks in advance.
